# Criteria from table 1 to table 2 result

Tags: php, sql

I Have 2 Table

Users

```
User    Role    Skill1  Skill2  Skill3  Skill4
user1   TSR Yes No  Yes No
user2   CSR No  Yes No  Yes
user3   TSR Yes Yes Yes No
```

Question

```
Question    Role    Skill1  Skill2  Skill3  Skill4
Quest 1 CSR Yes Yes No  No
Quest 2 TSR No  Yes Yes No
Quest 3 TSR No  Yes No  Yes
Quest 4 TSR No  No  No  Yes
Quest 5 CSR Yes Yes Yes No
```

I want to search on question based on the role and skill of user.

For example. If user1 has role of TSR with Skill1 and skill3 then the result on question is quest1, quest2 and quest5.

Here is my code, but the result is not what I want to be:

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$user' ") or    die(mysql_error());
while($validaterow = mysql_fetch_row($query1)){

$takenyes = $validaterow[6];

$tsr = $validaterow[5];
$csr = $validaterow[5];
$au = $validaterow[8];
$eu = $validaterow[9];
$me = $validaterow[10];
$jp = $validaterow[11];
$ca = $validaterow[12];
$na = $validaterow[13];
}



$sql="SELECT * FROM question WHERE (tsr='$tsr' OR csr='$csr') AND (skill1='$skill1' OR skill2='$skill2' OR skill4='$skill4' OR skill5='$skill5')";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Can you try to be a little more clear on what you're wanting vs what you're getting?

Comment: There's a few errors in here...might help if you tell us what you are looking for. Example - WHERE (tsr='$tsr' OR csr='$csr') your field name is role, not tsr/csr.  What exactly are you comparing tsr to?

Answer (score 0):

From your sample results, the `role` doesn't play any role at all.  You just want to get questions where there is a "yes" in the corresponding row in both tables.

You can do this using a `join`:

```
select q
from users u join
     questions q
     on u.Username='$user' and
        (u.skill1 = 'yes' and q.skill1 = 'yes' or
         u.skill2 = 'yes' and q.skill2 = 'yes' or
         u.skill3 = 'yes' and q.skill3 = 'yes' or
         u.skill4 = 'yes' and q.skill4 = 'yes'
        ) ;
```

Two comments:  you should learn to use "mysqli_" or PDO instead of the outdated "mysql_" interface.  Along the way, learn to parameterize queries.

Second, when you have multiple columns in a table with the same name, such as the skills, this often indicates that you want to normalize the table.  That is, have another table `UserSkills` with one row per user and one row per skill.  Similarly for the `questions` table.